# Heroku db pull error, it's looking for sqlite3 but I have postgres, how to change this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, taps

I have taps installed.
I get the following error.
This is my first pull like this from Heroku so I am unsure of the exact format

```
$ heroku db:pull postgres://postgres:@localhost/prod_20120717

 !    Taps Load Error: cannot load such file -- sqlite3
 !    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
 !    On most systems this will be:
 !    
 !    sudo gem install taps
```

I have created an empty `prod_20120717` in postgres to receive the data but the problem seems to be that taps is looking for sqlite3, not postgres.

My postgres user is postgres, no pw.

My database.yml file only has postgres adapter defined.

It seems like an adapter name issue.  I have also tried `postgresql` in both of the places where I have `postgres`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that I actually didn't have sqlite3 installed (I am on a Mac and my app just uses postgres) and I had to install it (sqlite3).

```
[sudo] gem install sqlite3
```

I didn't need it in my Gemfile I just needed it installed on my machine.

Answer (score 5):

Just a hunch, but i think sqlite is a requirement of taps:

https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/blob/master/lib/taps/cli.rb line 10:

```
require 'sqlite3'
```

I don't think this is to do with your actual app, but more the workings of taps itself, perhaps install the gem and go from there?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your gemfile setup like this?

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```